# Add @ElementCollection of enum in JHipsterEntity

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I have an entity A to which I want to add a list of an enum type so I add in the JPA entitys code

```
@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "tags")
private List<Tag> tags;
```

and run the `liquibase:diff` goal which according to my understanding should add necessary db and ui changes, but when I build and run my app the updates are not applied in db nor the UI.

How could I achieve this in a JHipster?

Thank you

Comment: After you run the `liquibase:diff` can you check there there is a new file under `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/`, with your changes. If yes you should include that file under the liquibase `master.xml` under `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/`. There are existing include files there for your A entity like `<include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_added_entity_A.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>`

Comment: FYI as per **JHipster** best practise you should go with `jhipster entity A` and choose the `Yes, add more fields and relationships` options. For example you add a `? What is the name of your field?` -> `gender` and choose the `❯ Enumeration (Java enum type)`

Comment: There is no option to add a list (or any kind of collection) of an enum, and cannot create a relationship with an enum. Regardless adding the changelog to master.xml created the db table.

Comment: Please heck the JHipster [entity doc](https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/) under field types.